# Interesting Round Trip Time behaviour

Tags: networking, internet

I'm working on a module on networking at the moment, and some coursework involved pinging different websites to investigate the Round-Trip-Time. I noticed something interesting while doing it which has left me puzzled and seeking an explanation. If I type `ping -4 google.com`, the RTT is significantly different than if I type `ping -4 www.google.com`. What I find particularly strange is that the time is not faster or slower every time; sometimes it's faster, and sometimes it's slower. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to that is really simple: Same name != same host. Google uses DNS-based load balancing. Just use a proper DNS client to see what’s going on:

```
$ dig www.google.com @8.8.4.4

; <<>> DiG 9.11.1-P3 <<>> www.google.com @8.8.4.4
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 19808
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.google.com.     45  IN  A   172.217.21.228

;; Query time: 13 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.4.4#53(8.8.4.4)
;; WHEN: Sat Oct 28 22:19:15 CEST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 59
```

The time-to-live (TTL) of the reply is very low: Just 45 seconds. Sure enough, after that time, a different IP address comes up:

```
$ dig www.google.com @8.8.4.4

; <<>> DiG 9.11.1-P3 <<>> www.google.com @8.8.4.4
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 47841
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.google.com.     299 IN  A   216.58.206.4

;; Query time: 14 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.4.4#53(8.8.4.4)
;; WHEN: Sat Oct 28 22:19:40 CEST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 59
```

Again, the TTL is very low: 5 minutes. With a TTL this short, you’re likely to test stuff longer than it takes for cached DNS replies to expire.

This is of course also true for querying with `www.` or without or perhaps other subdomains like `maps.` or `mail.` or whatever. With those, you’re more likely get different replies because you’re asking for different names.